# Kendo UI grid group e.slice is not a function error

Tags: jquery, ajax, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

Everything works good until serverGrouping is activated and I drag and drop some column to group data.

On javascript console the error is: 
e.slice is not a function.

I think that json obtained as response from ajax request has something wrong for grouped results. The real problem is that I cannot find anywhere an example about that.

At this moment I created a simple php script that returns a static array of objects:

```
{'results':[{'c0': 'row 0 col 0 value', 'c1': 'row 0 col 1 value'}, {'c0': 'row 1 col 0 value', 'c1': 'row 1 col 1 value'}], 'total': 20, 'group':[{field: 'c0', dir: 'asc'}]}
```

Group properties is initialized only if $_REQUEST has key 'group'.
And grid has property schema set in this way:

```
schema: {
            data: "results",
            total: "total",
            group: "group",
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible a bug in the grid. Only way to bypass is to disable server grouping.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return the data from the server in a separate property (which you've called *results*), as data should be contained within the *group* property. See http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.groups.

Your code should also be `groups: "group"`, not `group: "group`.